# My model wont move when using a rig

Tags: rigging, objects, error

Im new to blender and i got a model from SRB2 and when i put it into blender and made a mesh it didnt work.
Yes I did redo it. It still didnt work.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12WLnvCfpVt1g9bjTcerFtv5MI-9XV9nA?usp=sharing
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping vertices, select the whole mesh in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* and parent again *With Automatic Weights*.

Result:

[image]

Comment: That didnt work. It just gave me a thing with change bone layers.

Comment: @Dbnart Infinity Well, see my edit, it seems to work, it needs some manual corrections though

Comment: I found the merge by distance thing yet it didnt do anything to the model. are the polygons on the inside still supposed to be there?

Comment: Merge by Distance removes hundreds of overlapping vertices, they prevent any parenting, as you see now it works, but there may still be some problems, I see floating edges in your object, you need to fix that as well